# laravel 5.3 PDOException no database selected

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Please help me rectify this challenge i have with my migration. 
This is my .env file
[.env snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb7CU.jpg)

and this is my cmd with error message
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVHWu.jpg)

Comment: cos your `DB_DATABASE` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You should define DB you'll use in `.env` file:

```
DB_DATABASE = myproject
```

Comment: Is that not asked several times before ?